# RDP User Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp

I created user for RDP into Azure VM and was using it for few times, today I tried to login but I have forgotten what user I used. Is there any way to se what was the user and maybe password for RDP to VM machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reset the admin user password of your server, if you don’t remenber the name of this, don’t worry this action will create another one.
select Reset password under Help > enter a username (new one if you don’t know the old one) and a password

Comment: Yes, thx it worked out! Awsome!!!